# Throw a NotImplementedError in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler, webscarab

when I try to run my code I face with this issue I have defined a real-time request for this scraping but still does not working. anyone knows how to deal with this issue in python?
How sitemap is important in this case?
Thanks in advance

```
import logging
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from content.spiders.templates.sitemap_template import ModSitemapSpider
from content.models import db_connect, create_db_table, Articles
from content.items import ContentItems
from content.item_functions import (process_item,
                                process_singular_item,
                                process_date_item,
                                process_array_item,
                                process_plural_texts,
                                process_external_links,
                                process_article_text)

HEADER_XPATH = ['//h1[@class="article-title"]//text()']
AUTHOR_XPATH = ['//span[@class="cnnbyline"]//text()',
            '//span[@class="byline"]//text()']
PUBDATE_XPATH = ['//span[@class="cnnDateStamp"]//text()']
TAGS_XPATH = ['']
CATEGORY_XPATH = ['']
TEXT = ['//div[@id="storytext"]//text()',
    '//div[@id="storycontent"]//p//text()']
INTERLINKS = ['//span[@class="inStoryHeading"]//a/@href']
DATE_FORMAT_STRING = '%Y-%m-%d'


class CNNnewsSpider(ModSitemapSpider):

    name = 'cnn'
    allowed_domains = ["cnn.com"]
    sitemap_urls = ["http://edition.cnn.com/sitemaps/sitemap-news.xml"]


def parse(self, response):
    items = []
    item = ContentItems()
    item['title'] = process_singular_item(self, response, HEADER_XPATH, single=True)
    item['resource'] = urlparse(response.url).hostname
    item['author'] = process_array_item(self, response, AUTHOR_XPATH, single=False)
    item['pubdate'] = process_date_item(self, response, PUBDATE_XPATH, DATE_FORMAT_STRING, single=True)
    item['tags'] = process_plural_texts(self, response, TAGS_XPATH, single=False)
    item['category'] = process_array_item(self, response, CATEGORY_XPATH, single=False)
    item['article_text'] = process_article_text(self, response, TEXT)
    item['external_links'] = process_external_links(self, response, INTERLINKS, single=False)
    item['link'] = response.url
    items.append(item)
    return items
```

This is my Text result:

```
File "/home/nik/project/lib/python3.5/site-      packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 76, in parse
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2016-10-17 18:48:04 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET     http://edition.cnn.com/2016/10/15/opinions/the-black-panthers-heirs-after-50-     years-joseph/index.html> from <GET http://www.cnn.com/2016/10/15/opinions/the-     black-panthers-heirs-after-50-years-joseph/index.html>
2016-10-17 18:48:04 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET   http://edition.cnn.com/2016/10/15/africa/montreal-climate-change-hfc-  kigali/index.html> from <GET http://www.cnn.com/2016/10/15/africa/montreal-  climate-change-hfc-kigali/index.html>
2016-10-17 18:48:04 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://edition.cnn.com/2016/10/14/middleeast/battle-for-mosul-hawija-iraq/index.html> from <GET http://www.cnn.com/2016/10/14/middleeast/battle-for-mosul-hawija-iraq/index.html>
2016-10-17 18:48:04 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET    http://edition.cnn.com/2016/10/15/politics/donald-trump-hillary-clinton-drug-    test/index.html> (referer: http://edition.cnn.com/sitemaps/sitemap-news.xml)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nik/project/lib/python3.5/site-   packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 587, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/home/nik/project/lib/python3.5/site-   packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 76, in parse
raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Generally you should post relevant text as text, not as a link to a screenshot.

Comment: @khelwood,Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Do you really need all of those imports to replicate this problem? Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you gone to the scrapy support forums to ask? Stackoverflow isn't designed to do product support.

Comment: @BryanOakley, these imports come from the project, yes I did but so far no one answers me. if you know how to help just do it. thanks anyway

Comment: It doesn't matter if the imports come from the project. The point is that you should provide the _minimal_ amount of code to replicate the problem. Many people won't go to the trouble to run code that has a bunch of imports that they may not have installed. You need to take the time to remove _everything_ that you can while still reproducing the problem. This is as much for you as for the people answering your question; it helps you narrow down the code to help _you_ find an answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley, you are definitely right but, do you know why I get this NotImplementedError here? why it works for other websites correctly but for other it does not?

Comment: ModSitemapSpider is your own code, correct?  I don't see any references to it online.  If so, please post its source.

Comment: @nephtes, yes that's right, I do not use references except site map. may I ask what's your idea?

Comment: @Thomas The exception you're seeing is thrown [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L76).  This suggests that your spider class, `CNNnewsSpider`, does not override the `parse()` method, and neither do any of its base classes, beginning with `ModSitemapSpider`.  If that's the case, perhaps the chain of inheritance should start at `CrawlSpider` rather than `BaseSpider`, but it's impossible to say for sure without seeing the base classes in question.

Comment: @nephtes, thanks a lot, but when I change it to other classes like CrawlSpider, this will be my result:
'downloader/request_bytes': 432,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 886,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
Spider closed (finished)

Comment: @Thomas aaaah, now I understand.  Because of its indentation, the `parse()` you're defining is not being included in your `CNNnewsSpider` class.  Instead, it's a separate freestanding function.  Indent the entire definition and body of `parse()` by four spaces and it should be fine.  And it should be possible to keep the `BaseSpider` class.

Comment: @nephtes, would you please illustrate it if you don't mind? I appreciate that, I still get the same result :(((

Comment: @Thomas: see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is being thrown because your class `CNNnewsSpider` does not override the method `parse()` from `scrapy.BaseSpider`.  Although you are defining a `parse()` method in the code you pasted, it is not being included in `CNNnewsSpider` because of indentation: instead, it is being defined as a standalone function.  You need to fix your indentation as follows:

```
class CNNnewsSpider(ModSitemapSpider):
    name = 'cnn'
    allowed_domains = ["cnn.com"]
    sitemap_urls = ["http://edition.cnn.com/sitemaps/sitemap-news.xml"]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        item = ContentItems()
        item['title'] = process_singular_item(self, response, HEADER_XPATH, single=True)
        item['resource'] = urlparse(response.url).hostname
        item['author'] = process_array_item(self, response, AUTHOR_XPATH, single=False)
        item['pubdate'] = process_date_item(self, response, PUBDATE_XPATH, DATE_FORMAT_STRING, single=True)
        item['tags'] = process_plural_texts(self, response, TAGS_XPATH, single=False)
        item['category'] = process_array_item(self, response, CATEGORY_XPATH, single=False)
        item['article_text'] = process_article_text(self, response, TEXT)
        item['external_links'] = process_external_links(self, response, INTERLINKS, single=False)
        item['link'] = response.url
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your caring @nephtes,I did that but I still get the result which is "NotImplementedError" :((

Comment: ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://edition.cnn.com/2016/10/17/opinions/fight-against-isis-mosul-bergen/index.html (referer:http://edition.cnn.com/sitemaps/sitemap-news.xml)Traceback (most recent call last):File "/home/nik/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 587, in _runCallbacks current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)File "/home/nik/project/lib/python3.5/sitepackages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 76, in parseraise NotImplementedError

Comment: scrapy crawl  "name of class"

Comment: What are you actually using for "name of class"?

Comment: I did not change anything those are my codes, that's all